# Freya with kernel 3.19.0-51 fails to boot

Tags: release-freya, kernel

[image]

After updates my Freya system got a new kernel 3.19.0-51; but after restart Freya booting hangs with this kernel version
please see the kernel message below where it hangs

It is booting properly with kernel 3.19.0-49-generic

Should I wait till the next kernel update?

Comment: Mine runs with kernel 4.1 because my hardware was a little buggy

Comment: Is this a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes it is a VMware11

Comment: Remove the new kernel with synaptic

Comment: I have used synaptic to remove the kernel 3.19.0-51; thanks for the quick tip

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) and type `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.19.0-49-generic` and press enter.This will remove the new kernel.

WARNING : If you have removed the old kernel your VM may stop booting